# Problem with auth attempt with dynamic guard

Tags: laravel, authentication, web, laravel-8

Why `Auth::guard($request->type)->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])` returns false?

In login Controller

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        if (Auth::guard($request->type)->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            return $this->redirect($request);
        }

    }
```

In Auth Trait, functions that will be used in login controller

```
    public function redirect($request)
    {

        if ($request->type == 'student') {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::STUDENT);
        } elseif ($request->type == 'instructor') {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::INSTRUCTOR);
        } elseif ($request->type == 'admin') {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN);
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }
```

In config/Auth.php

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'student' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],
        'instructor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'instructors',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Student::class,
        ],
        'instructors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Instructor::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
```

First the user will select his type if he student or instructor or admin then when he select it redirect him to login form with his type ,when he press submit it will redirect to blank page

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the models used for login as "Authenticatable" ?

Like this in "Models" definition

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable {}
```

And also those models/table should have the columns in the "attempt" method defined in them.

Comment: Yes I did it before what data type of attempt in the database

Comment: Your models have email and password columns? Are passwords hashed in your models? Are you using plain text password in the request/attempt method?
Check you $request is well formed and with the data expected
Are you sure error is in "if" statement? Try "dd()" something in "if" and add something after it to check whether the "if" is creating trouble, or the redirect is the one not working.